# discord.js discord owner command only

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command that can only be used by the discord bot owner. If I use the code below, which should work, it just crashes.

All commends have their own files to keep it a bit cleaner.

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'pi',
  aliases: [],
  category: 'beta',
  utilisation: '{prefix}pi',
]
    [const userID = '<@654353673513861130>'

    if(!message.author === userID)
    execute(_client, message) {
        message.channel.send(`yooo`);
    },
};
```

Comment: Can you please reformat your code to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

one mistake that i noticed is you provided the ID with <@> as a string, replace the const with this

`const userID = '654353673513861130';`

if you are confused about making seperate files for commands, read [this](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) doc

Answer (score 0):

You can't wrap an object method (`execute` in this case) in an if statement. The if statement should be inside that method itself.

If you know the discord bot's owner's ID (`654353673513861130`, not `<@654353673513861130>`), you can check if it's the same as the message author's ID. If it's not the same, you can stop executing the command by `return`ing early. Anything after this `return` statement will run only if the author is the bot owner. Check the code below:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'pi',
  aliases: [],
  category: 'beta',
  utilisation: '{prefix}pi',
  execute(_client, message) {
    const ownerID = '654353673513861130';

    // if the ID is NOT the same, return early to exit
    if (message.author.id !== ownerID) return;

    // rest of the code is only run if the author is the bot owner
    message.channel.send(
      `I know you're the owner, ${message.author}. I mean, I know that your discord ID is ${ownerID}`,
    );
  },
};
```